# What are the types of storyboard in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, types, storyboard

I have recently given an interview. I was asked this question in interview. I read an article [[http://bitslot.info/ch13lev1sec1.shtml][1].](http://bitslot.info/ch13lev1sec1.shtml) This article explain me the types of storyboard. Are active, passive and interactive storyboard are types of storyboard in silverlight?

Comment: The article link is incorrect as it is discussing some other Storyboard which is not related to Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Types of Animation (Storyboard)* in `Silverlight`/`WPF`

1. **DoubleAnimation:** This will animate a Double Value from one value to another. So if you want to change the Width of a TextBox over time you need DoubleAnimation.
2. **ColorAnimation:** Same as the above if the type of Changing element is Color, you need ColorAnimation.
3. **Transformation:** This will animate the rendering of the shape (e.g Ractangle). 
   There are a variety of transformations that can take place, such as *stretching*, *skewing*, *rotating*, etc.
4. **SingleAnimation, RectAnimation, PointAnimation, Int32Animaition, ThicknessAnimation** etc each of them bears the same meaning.

So basically the basis of Animation types is based on the type of the property for which you want your animation to work on.

Animation can also be *categorized* into two basic ways:

1. **Animation Without KeyFrames:** These are animation that only needs two values, From and To. It gives you a smooth animation based on the Timeline.DesiredFramerate property for the animation.
2. **Animation With KeyFrames:** Allows you to specify a KeyFrame collection which lets you define the KeyFrame value on a specified time. So that you can adjust your own animation based on specific time intervals.

These references might provide you good information further regarding `Animation (Storyboard)` Types and their Usage:

1. [Introduction to WPF Animations](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/IntroductionToWPFAnimations.aspx)
2. [WPF Tutorial - Styles, Triggers & Animation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140623/WPF-Tutorial-Styles-Triggers-Animation)
3. [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)
4. [Storyboards Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx)

Comment: Did you mean types of storyboard and types of animation are same thing?

Comment: Yes sort of, Storyboard is the way to perform animation especially in the Xaml, A storyboard determines at what point in time a frame will occupy a specific position and will have specific properties. http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wpf-storyboard-%E2%80%93-what-it-and